# A simple Matchstick puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

Here is a simple matchstick puzzle. Some creative thinking may be needed.

Make the equation below correct by moving only **one** matchstick. The use of > or < or *not equal to* is not allowed. You can't remove the matchstick either.

18 = 08

[image]

Comment: probably not what you intended, but rot13(lbh pbhyq "zbir" bar bs gur zngpufgvpxf bs gur "1" gb yvtug vg, chg vg ba gur bgure zngpufgvpx va gur "1" naq jura gurl jrer erqhprq gb nfu, lbh'q unir gur pbeerpg rdhngvba rvtug rdhnyf mreb rvtug)

Comment: LOL @SteveV. Just moving though. No lighting!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hmmm... a [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag? And creative thinking needed? Okay, why don't we...

> ...remove the match at the top of the first '8' and place it horizontally at the bottom of the '1', then rotate our viewpoint by 180 degrees (i.e. turn everything upside down). Our 'equation' now appears to spell out '**80 = AT**' - a phonetic representation of the number! (A.T. = ay-tee)
>
>  [image]

Comment: BOAT?  What does--oh, nevermind.

Comment: Very creative solution! I was surprised it was the intended one given that it moves *all* of the matchsticks.

Comment: @noedne Technically, we still only move one matchstick - the rest of the work is done by moving yourself to view it from a different angle :)

Answer (score 35):

It seems to me that

> Positive eight is equal to zero-padded eight
>  [image: Plus eight (positive eight, in other words), equals zero eight, in matchsticks]

Comment: I did not think of this creative solution, probably because + sign is moved downward. My solution is different. Nice job.

Answer (score 21):

Using some creative thinking,

> we can stand a matchstick on its end to obtain $\dot{18}=00$.
>  [image: dot over eighteen equals zero zero]
>  The left-hand side can be interpreted as the derivative of a constant function using [Newton's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton%27s_notation), which is equal to 0.

Answer (score 13):

We can make the following equality by moving one match:

> 18 = 018
>  [image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this counts since the sticks are a bit short but, |8|=08 .[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move the matchstick from the bottom of the 0 to the top left of the 1 and then rotate 180 degrees. No mention of anything about the equation being true for all values, so in this case the equation is true if U is equal to L!

[image]

Comment: in C/C++ style, 8 (unsigned integer value) is equal to 8 (long integer value).

Comment: Indeed, in many programming languages (like C#, VB, F#), ‘U’ and ‘L’ suffixes denote unsigned and long integers, which are equal in positive range of the longs. Good find!

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view

> the left 8 can be horizontal and become infinite.

so

> it can be `1/inf = 00`

> [image]

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assign alphabetical numbers value like A = 1, B = 2, etc. Then, rotate the puzzle 180 degrees. Now we have "80 = 81". If we then move the bottom stick in the "0" to the middle, we get "8A = 81". which, following the values, would be "81 = 81" and satisfies all conditions.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

maybe : 16 >= 08 ? in case >= is allowed, which is **not** (> **or** < **or** *not equal to*) ...

Comment: How do you get that by moving only one matchstick?

Comment: @bobble $ \ge $

Comment: fwiw : it could have been 10>=08 as well but still not sure if **>=** is allowed

Answer (score -1):

I removed the bottom matchstick from the 8 on the left side of the equation making the left side say 1A. I placed that matchstick in the middle of 0 on the right side of the equation making the right side say 88. The whole equation: 1A=88. The puzzle never said anything about the equation being true for all values. In my case, the equation is only true if A is equal to 88.

Comment: Does this answer work?

Comment: Could you show an image of ur solution?