# Can you punctuate this?

Tags: wordplay

That that
is is
that that
is not
is not
is that
it it
is

Comment: A classic, but there's also the extended version: *"That that is is that that is not is not that that is is not that that is not that that is not is not that that is is that it it is"*

Comment: Are spoiler tags no longer a thing?

Comment: The question was closed by MODS, because "it is not fully defined" and may get "speculative answers" .... Due to the way it is (unintentionally) Posed, it can only be answered YES or NO, with only 2 Possible answers. The YES answer may be followed by a Proof, or Punctuated Sentences. I am making this comment with a Bias in view of (1) new users (2) my own answer (3) lots of other "unclosed" questions with lots of "speculative answers". ---- continued ----

Comment: ---- continued ---- EG This Popular Question [[ https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114774/a-simple-matchstick-puzzle ]] has 10 Different answers, with 4 answers having more than 10 votes. This seems to the very Definition of "not fully defined" and having "speculative answers". Let us not treat new users with Different rules than long term users.

Comment: @Prem Actually none of the users who voted to close this question are mods. Plus part of the motive behind closing it is likely that there is very little that is genuinely 'puzzle-y' about it - it's an exercise in punctuating a sentence, little more than that. Note also that with matchstick puzzles like the one you link there is a 'lateral-thinking' tag - this often leads to far more answers than the typical question on Puzzling. This is not a 'mods vs new users' situation - for many reasons! :)

Comment: @Prem The question you linked has now been closed.

Comment: @noedne , thanks for the update !

Comment: @Stiv , thanks for the clarification ! I was using that term loosely; My intent is not against some Puzzles or some users; It is only to treat all users equally; Perceptions may be wrong, but I see that Certain Puzzles by new users get Downvoted/Closed/Deleted quickly but Equal-Quality Puzzles by stable users get the benefit of Doubt.

Comment: @Prem No problem :) And it's good to raise perceived injustices, in case there's some kind of (unconscious) bias lurking beneath that can be addressed. Thanks for engaging...

Answer (score 18):

Can you punctuate this?
YES!

Punctuating "That that is is that that is not is not is that it it is"

That that is, is. That that is not, is not. Is that it? It is.

Meaning:
Statement: That which exists is existing. That which does not exist, is not existing.
Query: Is that all you want to state? OR Is that true?
Answer: That is all I want to state. OR That is true.

Comment: I originally saw this with an extra 'not': "that that is is that that is not is not is not that it it is". The punctuation falls out the same: "That that is, is. That that is not, is not. Is not that it? It is."

Answer (score 3):

"That that is is that that is not is not is that it it is" can also be punctuated as follows:

"'That that is' is 'that that is'; 'not' is 'not'."

"Is that it?"

"It is"

Answer (score 0):

Alternative punctuations from a person conjecturing alone:

That? That is. Is that? That? Is not. Is not? Is that? It? It is.

That? That is. Is that, that? Is not. Is? Not. Is that it? It is.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

> That, that is, is that that is not: is not is that it, it, is.

could analyzed to mean:

"That" i.e. being specific on given thing

"that is" , this is extra information specifying that year it is what we are referring to

"is that that is not" - meaning the referred is pretending to be a thing

*we could have second phrase being its own sentence and punctuating with a full-stop were it to have started with it, but it doesn't so we use a colon to mean is a continuation of beginning phrase giving some sort of extra information or explanation or redundancy.*

"Is not it that it" - first half of phrase

"it"- an extra information just like 'that is' i.e. emphasizing on it

"is" - continuation of the first half after the extra information.

validating our answer we could remove the extra information and it sounds sensible

**First phrase** (*before colon*)

> That is that that is not.

then maybe rephrase

> That is not what it is

we could have second phrase being its own sentence and punctuating with a full-stop were it to have started with it, but it doesn't so we use a colon to mean is a continuation of beginning phrase giving some sort of extra information or explanation or redundancy.

**second phrase**

> is not is that it is.

which could be rephrased as

> it is not what it seems to be

*this is justifiable with the way that and what relate, and way is is a form of be*

Comment: hey what did you edit? @bobble

Comment: Please see my edit summary. Code formatting hurts accessibility, especially for screen readers, and is semantically incorrect. [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/1017231)

Comment: oh got it, but i did not use it for emphasis, i used it to wrap original prose as was. but ok i am from overflow, a coder, so too so i may have overused it. ok then

Answer (score 0):

"That that is is that that" is not "is not is that it it is". (so true)